# Determine whether a relationship/association is required

Tags: entity-framework

I'm currently in a situation where I'm writing a multi-tier application using EF6 for the datalayer.

Because of the clients this application is targeting everything needs to either been testable either using unit tests or integration tests.

Consequently, I'm developing an `EntityTypeConfiguration` for one of my entities that defines a required relationship.

What I'd like to do in the tests is test whether the relationship is required.

Currently the required test in XUnit looks as follows:

```
        AvailableSearchConfiguration config = new AvailableSearchConfiguration();
        DbModelBuilder builder = new DbModelBuilder();
        builder.Configurations.Add(config);
        DbModel model = builder.Build(new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2008"));
        PropertyInfo DatabaseMappingProperty = model.GetType().GetProperty("DatabaseMapping", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object databaseMapping = DatabaseMappingProperty.GetValue(model, null);
        PropertyInfo modelPropertyInfo = databaseMapping.GetType().GetProperty("Model");
        EdmModel edmModel = (EdmModel)modelPropertyInfo.GetValue(databaseMapping, null);
        EntityType availableSearchType = from e in edmModel.EntityTypes where e.Name =="AvailableSearch" select e;
        NavigationProperty datasets =from np in availableSearchType.NavigationProperties where np.Name =="Datasets" select np;
```

How, given the above, do I determine the multiplicity of a relationship, i.e that it is indeed required.

Comment: It would be more in the nature of unit test to create an entity without a required association and see if it fails validation. You're not testing application logic now.